# Not seeing any improvement in speed by using Concurrent Chunk Upload

Tags: fine-uploader

uploader 5 to upload large videos to S3 and we are using php.

As per documentation from fineuploader the upload speed should increase if we enable concurrent chunk upload, we didn't see any improvement, below is the configuration we are using please suggest if we are missing some thing.

Our Statistics: 
       152 MB file Upload to S3 without Concurrent Chunk Enabled: 7:40 sec
       152 MB file Upload to S3 with Concurrent Chunk Enabled: 7:29 sec

Below is the Code we are using to enable Concurrent Chunk Upload:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var idUpload = "fineuploader-s3";
    $('#'+idUpload).fineUploaderS3({
    debug: true,
    request: {
            // REQUIRED: We are using a custom domain
            // for our S3 bucket, in this case.  You can
            // use any valid URL that points to your bucket.
            //endpoint: "http://testvibloo.s3.amazonaws.com",
            endpoint: "testvibloo.s3.amazonaws.com",

            // REQUIRED: The AWS public key for the client-side user
            // we provisioned.
            accessKey: "AWS Access Key",

            forceMultipart: false,

        },
    objectProperties: {
        key: function(fileId) {
            var keyRetrieval = new qq.Promise(),
        filename = $("#"+idUpload).fineUploader("getName", fileId);
        keyRetrieval.success('testing/'+new Date().getTime()+'_'+filename);
        return keyRetrieval;
            }
        },

        template: "simple-previews-template",

        // REQUIRED: Path to our local server where requests
        // can be signed.
        signature: {
            endpoint: "http://hostname/testing/html/templates/s3demo.php"
        },

        // USUALLY REQUIRED: Blank file on the same domain
        // as this page, for IE9 and older support.
        iframeSupport: {
            localBlankPagePath: "success.html"
        },

        // optional feature
        chunking: {
            enabled: true,

             concurrent: {

                enabled: true, 

            },

        },

    //maxConnections: 5,
   // optional feature
        resume: {
            enabled: true
        },

        // optional feature
        validation: {
            sizeLimit: 1024 * 1024 * 1024
        },

    })
        // Enable the "view" link in the UI that allows the file to be downloaded/viewed
        .on('complete', function(event, id, name, response) {

            var $fileEl = $(this).fineUploaderS3("getItemByFileId", id),
                $viewBtn = $fileEl.find(".view-btn");

            if (response.success) {
                $viewBtn.show();
                $viewBtn.attr("href", response.tempLink);
            }
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> As per documentation from fineuploader the upload speed should increase if we enable concurrent chunk upload,

The documentation does not exactly say this.  Here's what it does say:

> There is a clear benefit in terms of upload speed when sending multiple chunks at once. The concurrent chunks feature is primarily in place to maximize bandwidth usage for single large file uploads.

Note that last sentence: "for single large file uploads".  If you are uploading multiple files at a time, you are already likely maxing out your connection to S3.  The concurrent chunking feature is aimed at ensuring all available connections are used for single file uploads.  Without this feature, only one connection would be used at a time.